How to show html code have multi TextDirection in same line in flutter?
I want to show html code in flutter that have English and Arabic words in same line
I use flutter_widget_from_html pub to handle with this but when i show code like
<p>ثاني اكسيد الكربون CO<sub>2</sub></p>

The sub text show in left because I put the text direction rtl

and the sub text should to the  right like this
 how to solve this problem
I try to change code to
<p dir="rtl">ثاني أكسيد الكربون</p> <p dir="ltr">CO<sub>2</sub></p>


but it will show in seperate lines and I want them in same line

How about using span or inline-block and reverse the actual tag order?


.inline { display: inline-block; }
<span dir="ltr">CO<sub>2</sub></span> <span dir="rtl">ثاني أكسيد الكربون</span>

<hr/>

<p class="inline" dir="ltr">CO<sub>2</sub></p>
<p class="inline" dir="rtl">ثاني أكسيد الكربون</p>



